# Autoregressive Timeseries (AR-1) and interpretation of autocorrelation plots

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive, acf-pacf

My understanding is as follows:

ACF-Plot: AR-k model shows highest correlation at lag k

PACF-Plot: PACF to only describe the direct relationship between an observation and its lag, so that there would be no correlation for lag values beyond k-lag

i generate an AR-1 Series. Plot the ACF / PACF and the aformentioned statement for the PACF does not hold, we see a correlation for a lag value >k (AR-1 model used for the data)

Edit:

-data are calculated as $y_{t} = b_{0}+b_{1} \cdot y_{t-1}+e_{t}$ with the code below

-choosen params $b_{0}=1$, $b_{1}=1$, $e_{t}=0.1$

data used for plotting ACF, PACF are differenced to remove the trend, meaning $y_{t}-y_{t-1}$

```
    x      y        y_diff
0   1   18.935535   NaN
1   2   20.035535   1.1
2   3   21.135535   1.1
3   4   22.235535   1.1
4   5   23.335535   1.1
... ... ...         ...
```

differenced data:

[image: differenced TS]

[image: ACF / PACF differenced TS]

How the data are made:

`````
def make_ar_1_series(series=False, y_minus1=False, starting_price =20.10, volatility=5.10, length=100, b0=1, b1=0.5, error=0.1):
    '''
    generate a timeseries according to an AR-1 Model
    y_minus1 = −1 (initial previous y-value),
    series = pd.Series of y_values, if false, generate pseudorandom normaly distributed startvalue with starting_price = loc = µ, 
    volatility = scale = sigma, b0,b1,error as guess following form =0+1⋅−1+
    '''
    x = range(1,length+1)
       
    if (series == False and y_minus1 == False):
        rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=12345)
        y_minus1 = rng.normal(loc=starting_price, scale=volatility, size=1)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y_minus1[0]})          
    elif (series == False and y_minus1):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y_minus1})          
    elif series:
        raise NotImplementedError('not implemented')
    else:
        return ('supplied undefined arguments or wrong values')
    
    for n in range(1,len(x)):
        df.loc[n::,('y')] = b0 + (df['y'].iloc[n-1]*b1) + error
    
    return df

df_ar1 = hp.make_ar_1_series(starting_price = 22.31, volatility = 2.37, length=1000, b0=1, b1=1, error=0.1)

````
`````

Comment: What does *differenced data* mean in your post?

Comment: edited the question, hope it made things more clear

Comment: What do $b_0$, $b_1$ and $e_t$ mean? Are they related to $\phi_0$, $\phi_1$ and $\sigma^2_e$? Regarding differencing the time series before doing ACF and PACF, are you familiar with the notion of overdifferencing? (If not, consider looking it up. There are a few posts mentioning it.)

Comment: ok, thank you for the tip, i had a look and for fractional differencing, the issue in my data can not be observed, i would delete the post since it is so trivial

Comment: What about the rest of my questions (about the coefficients)?

Comment: yes,  b0, b1 and et = ϕ0 , ϕ1 and σ2e

Comment: But it is $\sigma^2=0.1$, not $e_t=0.1$, right? Also, your parameters are a very special case of AR(1) which is known as a random walk. It would be more precise and more informative to call you model random walk than AR(1). Also, something must be wrong with your graphs. Differenced data is just $e_t$ which is white noise, so ACF and PACF should have only about 5% of all lags sticking out at random. The screenshot you have included shows something very different.